# How to add an action to a mysql, python written database

Tags: python, mysql, database

So I'm trying to make a project for school where a database stores the check_in and check_out time form an RFID card using a RFID reader.

```
create table attendance_check(
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
   date_id DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,  
   user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   clock_id TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
   Action VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
);
```

The database looks like this and for "Action" I want to add "in" and "out". I manage to add the "in" but can't figure out how to make a look-up and add an "out".
This is the code so far. I've tried 10 different variations already, I also have a database that stores the Users.

```
while True:
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message('Place Card to\nrecord attendance')
    id, text = reader.read()

    cursor.execute("Select id, name FROM users WHERE rfid_uid="+str(id))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    lcd.clear()
    name = result[1]
    number = result [0]
    action1 = "in"
    action2 = "out"
    if cursor.rowcount >= 1:
      lcd.message("Welcome " + name)
      add = ("INSERT INTO attendance_check (user_id, name, Action) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)")
      date = (numar, nume, action1)
      cursor.execute(add, date)
      db.commit()
    else:
      lcd.message("User does not exist.")
    time.sleep(2)
```

I've tried to use if statements inside that checks if an action is there and if it's "in" it should add "out" but it never worked

[It looks like this so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbh77.png)